# How to iterate an object array set in session scope using JSTL?

Tags: jsp, session, jstl

I have Manager bean which has array of associatedEmp. I am setting Manager bean to session by using `<c:set var="managerBean" value="${managerBean}" scope="session"  />`. Now in another jsp i am trying to iterate the Employee array by taking the manager bean from session.

```
  <c:if test="${fn:length(sessionScope.managerBean.associatedEmp) gt 0" >
                    <c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(sessionScope.managerBean.associatedEmp) - 1}" step="1"
                        varStatus="loopCounter"
                        items="${sessionScope.managerBean.associatedEmp}"
                        var="associatedEmployee">
<c:out value="${associatedEmployee.empId}" />
```

When i try this i am getting `"${fn:length(sessionScope.managerBean.associatedEmp) gt 0" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException"` .

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the length function. Is this the right way to do ?
Please help.

Thanks,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${fn:length(sessionScope.managerBean.associatedEmp) gt 0}
```

Closing bracket is missing.